# Simplify code: return a value from map if map is not null and contains key

Tags: java

Can the following piece of code be simplified?

```
    public Optional<String> myMethod(final Map myMap) {

        String result = null;
        if (myMap != null && myMap.containsKey(Constants.SOME_KEY)) {

            result = (String) myMap.get(Constants.SOME_KEY);
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(result);
    }
```

Comment: `get` will already return `null` when the map doesn't contain the key. The places where keys are associated with a `null` value are rare (and I personally consider them a bug).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try:

```java
public Optional<String> myMethod(final Map<String, String> myMap) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(myMap != null ? myMap.getOrDefault("Key", null) : null);
    }
```

Comment: Adding the Generics to `Map` seems wise.

Comment: I can't do that since it's from an external library that can give <String, Object>